# Связь заметок с пользователем через ключ

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace RazorWebApp.Models
{
    public class User
    {
            public int ID { get; set; }

    }





    public class Note
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string HeadLine { get; set; }
        public string Tag { get; set; }
        public DateTime Data { get; set; }
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public int Rating { get; set; }


        [Column(TypeName ="Image")]
        public byte[] Image { get; set; }



    }
}
```

`Проблема такая - есть веб  приложение на asp .net core , функционал такой - запускаем, авторизируемся, и можем создавать, редактировать и удалять заметки
суть в том, чтобы сделать так, чтобы заметки прикреплялись бы только к тому пользователю, который её создал.
вот код моего класса заметки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот мой контроллер собственно(то место, где как я понял мы получаем весь список текущих заметок)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же по-скольку я делал по конкретным документациям, хотелось бы немного прояснить суть запроса к бд, то есть как работает вот такой вот запрос

```
v

    ar notes = from m in _context.Note
                            select m;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
                {
                    notes = notes.Where(s => s.HeadLine.Contains(searchString));
                }
                return View(await notes.ToListAsync());
```

Потому что, как мне сказали, так как я работаю с энтити, то запросы можно делать гораздо проще, и поэтому если не сложно было бы неплохо если бы кто подсказал как сделать нормальный энтити запрос в котором мы скажем получим все текущие заметки и их айди

Так же прикрепляю ссылку на свой проект на гите, потому что хотелось бы именно на своем примере увидеть, что нужно изменить, чтобы заметки прикреплялись именно к определенному пользователю
https://github.com/SoClose172/RazorWebApp

вот код контроллера

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using RazorWebApp.Models;
using RazorWebApp.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization; 

namespace RazorWebApp.Controllers
{
    public class NotesController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public NotesController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        // GET: Notes
        [Authorize]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string searchString)
        {
            var notes = from m in _context.Note
                        select m;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                notes = notes.Where(s => s.HeadLine.Contains(searchString));
            }
            return View(await notes.ToListAsync());
        }

        // GET: Notes/Details/5
        [Authorize]

        public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var note = await _context.Note
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
            if (note == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(note);
        }

        // GET: Notes/Create
        [Authorize]

        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Notes/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ID,HeadLine,Tag,Data,Number,Rating,Image")] Note note)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Note.Add(note);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(note);
        }

        // GET: Notes/Edit/5
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var note = await _context.Note.FindAsync(id);
            if (note == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(note);
        }

        // POST: Notes/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [Authorize]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("ID,HeadLine,Tag,Data,Number,Rating,Image")] Note note)
        {
            if (id != note.ID)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                try
                {
                    _context.Update(note);
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
                {
                    if (!NoteExists(note.ID))
                    {
                        return NotFound();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(note);
        }

        // GET: Notes/Delete/5
        [Authorize]

        public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            var note = await _context.Note
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
            if (note == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return View(note);
        }

        // POST: Notes/Delete/5
        [Authorize]

        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            var note = await _context.Note.FindAsync(id);
            _context.Note.Remove(note);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }

        private bool NoteExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Note.Any(e => e.ID == id);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `вот код моего класса заметки` - я вижу только картинку... Разместите код текстом!

Comment: `чтобы заметки прикреплялись именно к определенному пользователю` - В чем трудность в хранение идентификатора пользователя (id/ник) в созданной заметке и по ней потом выводить все заметки пользователя?

Comment: не могли бы вы просто подробно распистаь где и как добавить вот проверку на то какой пользователь щас пишет(то есть проверку на айди)
и все такое

Comment: А как именно код тут присылать?

Comment: Так, весь код добавил

Comment: `как мне сказали, так как я работаю с энтити, то запросы можно делать гораздо проще` - так спросите там, где вам сказали, пусть они вам примеры дадут. А то мы вам насоветуем, а от вас ждут другой код.

Answer (score 1):

Вроде был пару часов назад такой вопрос же
Вам же там все ясно отписали как сделать

в контролере

```
public IActionResult AttachNote(int userId, Note note)
{
    var user = Repository.GetById(id);
    Repository.Add(note);
    user.Notes.Add(note);
    Repository.SaveChanges();
}
```

в юзере добавить связь

```
public class User
{
    public User()
    {
        Notes = new List<Note>() { get;set; }
    }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public  ICollection<Note> Notes { get;set; }
}
```

и в конструкторе класса юзера написать

```
Notes = new List<Note>() { get;set; }
```

Если у вас .net core то для того что бы в контролере принять модель как параметр надо его пометить атрибутом [FromBody]

```
public IActionResult AttachNote(int userId, [FromBody] Note note)
```

или можно просто текст передать и просто создать новый экземпляр Note  к методе

если надо все заметки и их id то так можно

```
var all = repository.Notes.Select(g => new 
{
   Id = g.Id,
   Text = g.Text
});
```

и можно обращаться так

```
foreach( var item in all) 
{
    $"{item.Text} {item.Id}"
}
```

Кстати увидело что у заметки есть картинка и вы как массива байтов храните. Лично я делал ты тип строку и в ней хранил путь до картинки на сервере
например http://localhost:8080/images/notes/main.jpg

то есть когда передадется картинка вы ее сохраняете с текущем именем или даете своем и потом создаете путь 
первая часть пути будет всегда статическая
то есть

http://localhost:8080/images/notes/ и потом ее им main.jpg в итоге будет

```
http://localhost:8080/images/notes/main.jpg
```

и базе хранить эту строку это очень удобно когда вы json отдаете ответ
будет выглядеть как-то так

```
[
  {
     "text": "Тест заметки",
      "image": "http://localhost:8080/images/notes/main.jpg "
  }
]
```

Comment: так у меня нет класса юзер, а если я его создам там же где к меня лежит класс заметки, то как этому классу юзер передавать значения юзеров которые у меня в бд хранятся?

Comment: не могли бы вы если вам не сложно прямо в моем проекте сделать правки, а то я до сих пор не понимаю что и как нужно сделать, вернее по тому гайду что вы прислали не особо получается, даже буду готов отблагодарить вас, если все заработает!!!

Comment: и еше немного не понял, там где написано репозиторий это как бы путь где зранятся наши пользватели?

Comment: репозиторий это context через который получаете данные с Бд

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40532987/how-to-extend-identityuser-with-custom-property вот тут написано как все сделать

Comment: у меня не вызывается getbyid

Comment: обновите вопрос с со скрином вызова